# Open Terminal App Without Opening A Window

Tags: terminal

Is it possible to change the default settings in the Terminal App (OS X 10.7.5) such that when the app is launched, no windows are opened by default?

As a shot in the dark, I tried closing all windows, and then creating an "empty" window group and setting that as what should be "opened" when the app is launched, but it is still opening a bash window when the app is launched.

(The reason I ask is that some other apps I use occasionally launch Terminal with a bash prompt in a particular directory, but I always get *two* windows open: the default one in my home directory and the one the other application opened.)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange that you say this, because I only get one window open... It would be interesting to see how the applications are launching the Terminal. IF they launch it by opening Terminal, then opening a new window using Applescript or something, then you would expect to see two new windows, but if they just run a bash script, then it should just open a single window.

Comment: The particular app is RStudio (rstudio.org). It has very basic git support; for anything advanced you want to do in git, RStudio opens a Terminal window in the relevant directory. But I _also_ get the default Terminal window in my home directory as well. I may have to take it up with the RStudio folks.

Comment: I noticed that they have a link to the source code on their website, so I suppose if it really bothers you and the RStudio people don't help, you could have a look through the source yourself... (This would take a lot of time, however...)

Comment: I've downloaded the app to have a look, and you're absolutely right about the behaviour of the app. One way you could sort of work around the issue is to start Terminal first, then close the window that opens, and leave Terminal open. That way it won't open the extra window.